# Create named Column default in CREATE TABLE statement in ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I want to create a named default value in an ANSI compliant fashion, if possible, in a CREATE TABLE statement

If I try to add the CONSTRAINT as I would normally write it in an ALTER TABLE statement, it fails (at least in SQL SERVER, though I emphasise I am hoping to find an ANSI complaint statement as I would prefer it to work over a variety of Ado.NET DbConnections).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyExample]
(
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
Name varchar(512) NOT NULL,         
IsActive bit NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_MyExample PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
CONSTRAINT DF_MyExample_IsActive  DEFAULT (1) FOR [IsActive]
)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'for'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of the SQL-92 Standard -- which is both ISO (I = International) and ANSI (A + American), by the way -- `DEFAULT` is not a constraint that may be given a name. In SQL-92 the `DEFAULT` can only be defined inline with the column definition and must be between the data type and the `NOT NULL` (if used) e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE T (c INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

Note you have much non-Standard syntax in your small example:

- square brackets as quoted identifiers (should be double quotes)
- non-compliant data type (e.g. incorrect `bit` null behaviour)
- abbreviated data types (e.g. `int` rather than `INTEGER`)
- `IDENTITY`
- `CLUSTERED`

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. Thanks also for the Mimer validator link. Too much SQL Server lately, I have to brush up :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it not ANSI compliant?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyExample]
(
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Name varchar(512) NOT NULL,         
    IsActive bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyExample_IsActive DEFAULT (1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyExample PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

Comment: @johnc: It is not ISO/IEC/ANSI SQL-92 compliant. This can be verified e.g. using  the [Mimer SQL-92 Validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml).